# Abort SqlRowsCopiedEventArgs

Tags: c#

i'm trying to abort bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
in the documentation i found the SqlRowsCopiedEventArgs.Abort Property which seems to be doing exactly what i need. but i don't understand exactly how to use it and i can't find an example for it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlrowscopiedeventargs.abort.aspx

I would vary much appreciate a working example of how the SqlRowsCopiedEventArgs.Abort property can be used to stop the bulkCopy.

my code:

```
  using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connDetails.ConnString)) {
                    bulkCopy.NotifyAfter = 1;
                    bulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied += (sender1, e1) =>
                    {
                        if (tryAbort == true)
                        {
                            Log.Info(" e1.Abort = true"); //this line never happens
                            e1.Abort = true;

                        }

                    };
                    bulkCopy.BatchSize =(int)(batchSize != null ? batchSize : (int)ConfigSettings.CSettings.SqlServerDefaultBatchSize);
                         bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
                         Log.Info("BatchSize:" + bulkCopy.BatchSize.ToString());
                         bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destinationTable;
                         while (reader.Read()) {
                             try
                             {
                                 bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                                 //bulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied
                             }
                             catch (Exception ex)
                             {
                                 Log.Info("Caught " + ex.GetType() + " while calling bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);");
                                 Log.Info("No records were added to destination");
                             }
                         }
```

when the user try to abort this function is called:

```
        public void sourceAbort()
    {
        tryAbort = true;
        conn.Dispose();

    }
```

Comment: See around Page 40 of https://books.google.com.au/books?id=6yWKYRcYPsQC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=sqlrowscopiedeventargs+sample&source=bl&ots=z_RZlweKm6&sig=iPJVT4OKwYE5IZ0V5xfHj4KzWMU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwib4MPtibvVAhWMppQKHSuCBvwQ6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=sqlrowscopiedeventargs%20sample&f=false . Or page 414 of https://books.google.com.au/books?id=ULMJ0_5I4MMC&pg=PA414&dq=sqlrowscopiedeventargs+sample+onrowscopied&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjow7vVirvVAhXCJpQKHeWsCUYQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=sqlrowscopiedeventargs%20sample%20onrowscopied&f=false .

Comment: What is not to understand about it? Once you want it to abort you set the `Abort` value to `true` in your event handler. After every x copied rows the event is raised so you can abort it. (x is defined by the [`NotifyAfter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.notifyafter.aspx) property)

Comment: I've added my code. anyone have an idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if the answer is late but here is a high level example:

```
 using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connStr))
{
     bulkCopy.NotifyAfter = x; // after how many rows of copy do you want a notif event
     bulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                               {
                                 if (someLogic) // some condition to abort                                          {      
                                         eventArgs.Abort = true;
                                        }                                        
                                };                                           
}
```

The SqlRowsCopied is called after x rows of copy